# Why does the first compilation of a simple C# project in Visual Studio take so long?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning C# through video tutorials by Bob Tabor on MSDN's Channel 9.  Whenever the instructor(Bob Tabor) hit the Start button(to compile and run), the result console window immediately appeared for him... but it (**first compilation only**) is taking atleast 20-30 seconds for me...

I have the latest Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on my Core i7 4th Gen laptop with 8 GB Ram.

Few days ago, I came to know that deleting %temp% folder will speed up launching of Visual Studio, and it worked for that purpose.

But, I'm not able to solve this **slow first compilation** problem... all subsequent code changes are compiled and run super fast... I'm guessing that there is a fix for this... I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: First compilation *ever*? Or first compilation after some event (e.g. a reboot or launch of VS)? Because for the former, it seems like something that can be ignored. For the latter, the *specific context* may be important.

Comment: Could this be a symptom of a failing hard drive? Some drives become slow before they actually fail, and OS's cache could be masking that on subsequent compilations? This is a wild guess, obviously...

Comment: This just sounds like normal operating system behaviour - when all of the files that VS needs to compile and build a debug environment are loaded from disk they are put in the disk cache; so then the second time that a compile is performed it's cached and super fast because it is coming from memory.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hi... I have been testing Visual Studio multiple times over the last few weeks and I can say confidently that reboot is the issue. Whenever I reboot windows 10( 64 bit), and open VS, it takes a lot of time to create a new project and also takes a lot of time to compile for the **first time** Could you suggest a fix for this please...

Answer (score 0):

try this as it worked for me

open run from start

type %temp% and delete everything from there...

open Run again and type prefetch and delete everything from there also.

now open VS and see the performance

Comment: Please explain 'prefetch'

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You are providing some instruction that doesn't explain if it is faster (or, for that matter, slower!) - and by how much. Please properly flesh out this answer.

Comment: He said there is a fix for why it is slower so i give him a solution for improve performance

Comment: @Aarsh - No, he asked, "Why does the first compilation of a simple C# project in Visual Studio take so long?" - You didn't answer that, you just told him to do some stuff without explaining why it helps or how much it helps.